# C# can't convert string to byte array to desired result?

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have string which is storing only 1's and 0's .. now i need to convert it to a byte array. I tried ..

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                        byte[] d = encoding.GetBytes(str5[1]);
```

but its giving me byte array of ASCIIs like 48's and 49's but i want 1's and 0's in my byte array.. can any one help

Comment: If you had a string of length 8, are you looking for a single byte, or 8 bytes with the top 7 bits of each being clear?

Comment: Are you expecting `"00110101"` to give you a byte of `53`?

Comment: @Matthew I don't think so: "i want 1's and 0's in my byte array"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the correct result from an encoding. An encoding produces *bytes*, not *bits*. If you want *bits*, then use bit-wise operators to inspect each byte. i.e.

```
foreach(var byte in d) {
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 1);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 2);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 4);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 8);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 16);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 32);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 64);
    Console.WriteLine(byte & 128);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                    byte[] d = encoding.GetBytes(str5[1]);
var dest[] = new byte();
var iCoun = 0;
var iPowe = 1;
foreach(var byte in d)
{
  dest[i++] = (byte & iPowe);
  iPowe *= 2;
}
foreach(var byte in dest)
{
  Console.WriteLine(byte);
}
```

Comment: based on marc's answer. In dest[] array you will find what you want!

Answer (score 0):

There is no UTF encoding required, you say you have a string of `'0'`s and `'1'`s (characters) and you want to get to an array of `0`s and `1`s (bytes):

```
var str = "0101010";
var bytes = str.Select(a => (byte)(a == '1' ? 1 : 0)).ToArray();
```